# Ошибка при сериализации класса

Tags: java, сериализация, serializable

Почему при сериализации класса, получаю ошибку:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream Closed

Ошибка исчезает, если удалить `out.close()` и `in.close()`. Почему нужно удалять?

```
public class Solution implements Serializable, AutoCloseable {
            transient private FileOutputStream stream;
            public Solution(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
                this.stream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            }
            public void writeObject(String string) throws IOException {
                stream.write(string.getBytes());
                stream.write("\n".getBytes());
                stream.flush();
            }
            private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
                out.defaultWriteObject();
                out.close();
            }
            private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
                in.defaultReadObject();
                in.close();
            }
            @Override
            public void close() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Closing everything!");
                stream.close();
            }
        }
```

Вызов выглядит так:

```
Solution sol = new Solution("b:/data.txt");
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("b:/data.txt"); 
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
objectOutputStream.writeObject(sol);
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("b:/data.txt");
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
Solution new_sol = (Solution) objectInputStream.readObject();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если взять отладчик и пройти пошагово, то можно увидеть, что после записи вашего объекта, в методе `ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData` дописывает в поток один байт, для какой-то своей протокольной надобности:

```
bout.setBlockDataMode(true);
slotDesc.invokeWriteObject(obj, this);
bout.setBlockDataMode(false);
bout.writeByte(TC_ENDBLOCKDATA);
```

Поскольку вы закрыли поток внутри своего метода, этот байт не может быть записан, и позже при попытке сбросить буфер, вылетает исключение.

Закрывать поток внутри вашего метода не надо, вдруг дальше будет запись еще одного объекта, но об этом код метода ничего не будет знать. Вообще, в Java принято освобождать ресурсы в том же коде, где их получили, через конструкцию `try-finally` (или `try-with-resources`), примерно так:

```
try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("b:/data.txt"); 
     ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream)) {
    objectOutputStream.writeObject(sol);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо,а почему в стэке сразу после записи объекта данного метода не вижу?

Comment: В смысле в сообщении об ошибке? В процессе записи вылетает исключение, внутри `writeObject` его ловят и пытаются записать в поток, попытка порождает еще одно исключение (поток все еще закрыт), и вот это второе исключение попадает в ошибку.

Comment: Ну Вы написали,что можно увидеть в методе ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData вот я и спросил,что не понимаю/не знаю как его увидеть

Comment: Можете в своем `private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out)` в конец `throw new RuntimeException()` дописать, вылетит исключение с трассой до этого метода. Я в eclipse точку остановки (breakpoint) поставил и в отладочном режиме (Debug) запустил.

Comment: Разобрался,а в eclipse сразу в отладочном режиме данный метод видно?

Comment: Да в любой IDE есть отладчик, в котором можно останавливать программу в указанной точке, выполнять по шагам с заходом внутрь методов и т.п. Исходники большей части классов приложены к JDK, можно смотреть, как все внутри устроено.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!